# Multiple Bind in HyperLinkButton Navigate URI

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am trying to build an app for Windows Phone 7.5 , I have some textblock that I bind some values from an xml file with the following code

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding People}" Foreground="White" />
```

Now I want to bind in a HyperLink Button 2 binds in the link. So I could create a facebook share.

```
<HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="4" Content="Share" TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={Binding People}&title={Binding Title}"/>
```

The above code don't work can you please guide me to make it work. I have already tried some alchemies with +,"'" and other stuff but doesn't seems to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. This is not string concatination

`NavigateUri="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={Binding People}&title={Binding Title}"`

What you need to do is create a `converter` and pass the object that contains `People` and `Title` to `converter`. Then inside `converter` create a `URI`

something like this. I am not sure about the syntax but you can get the main idea

```
NavigateUri={Binding Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}, ConverterParameter=''{Binding YourObject}"}
```

Then inside converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                 YourObject obj = (YourObject) value;
                 //create URI and return it
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thats a hell of a work for newbie like me (new knowledge), I'll try it. Thanks for the hint.